# Which ruby ORM framework to use in a standalone ruby app?

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, orm

I would like to use postgresql with foreign keys to define relationships in data so that other platforms/apps would also be able to easily use the same database. Having some kind of ruby DSL to define database schema with migration support would also be great. Which framework would you recommend for me?

Is there some kind of framework for only handling database schema changes, migrations and versions separate of ORM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/docs/). I [recently used it](http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2009/06/11/an-average-application-in-the-clouds) with Sinatra and deployed the app to Heroku. The only SQL I had to write was CREATE DATABASE. Everything else DataMapper provided for me with the .auto_migrate! and .auto_upgrade! functionality.

The foreign key support is in the dm-constraints plugin.

Comment: I stopped reading when I saw "one-to-one mapping between rows and objects."  That IMHO is a common mistake in ORM designs.  The two projects I've worked on that used such systems ran into nasty problems with transactions.

Comment: Please elaborate, I fail to see the connection.

Comment: and ActiveRecord has the same drawbacks anyway

Comment: @finnw Isn't "one-to-one mapping between rows and objects" the *point* of ORMs anyway?

Comment: @Félix Saparelli absolutely not. The point is to map objects to relational databases. There is *nothing* in that responsibility that constrains, nor even suggests, that objects should map one-to-one with rows. Composite objects spanning multiple tables. Multiple Value objects mapped to one record on one table. ORM is any-to-any.

Comment: Ruby + Postgres + DataMapper. Killer

Comment: project in archived status on github

Answer (score 6):

Between ActiveRecord and DataMapper I'd chose the latter. Both use the Active Record pattern, so you'll actually get your database tables back in objects without fancy domain logic, but DataMapper is way easier to work with, and is thread-safe. There is also [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/), but which I'm not familiar with.

If you need a framework to handle migrations I'd advise [merb](http://merbivore.org). Althoug it's a complete web framework starting 1.1 it can handle migrations for the three previously mentioned ORM framework (including separate and auto migrations)

Answer (score 2):

[M4DBI](https://github.com/Pistos/m4dbi) may also be of interest.  A low-level ORM which leverages DBI to allow you to write raw SQL if you like.

Comment: This looks like good work Pistos.  Your rationale is right on the mark.

Comment: @Michael: See [the github project](https://github.com/Pistos/m4dbi) though it's a bit of a dated framework now, since the underlying framework (Ruby DBI) has since been superseded by RDBI, and I haven't made the updates to M4DBI for that yet.

Comment: I have updated the code to work with the latest RDBI.

Answer (score -2):

Is there a good reason not to use [ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/)? It's kind of a standard for Ruby...

Comment: Yes.  The OP wants ts share a database between multiple applications.  This is not one of ActiveRecord's strong points.

Comment: Nothing about AR stops you doing that though.

Comment: standard doesn't mean good. It's dependency on ActiveSupport might be dangerous for a standalone app.

Comment: @SztupY Could you elaborate for newcomers why it is dangerous?

Comment: @mlt, I believe SztupY meant that ActiveSupport is doing too much monkey patching and newcomers may not understand that they have to not only look in AR's documentation but also in AS's too to find some methods. While it is not dangerous in book, IMHO it has to be used with caution in a non-Rails app.

Comment: ActiveRecord "it's kind of standard" for Rails, not Ruby